Set of reduced words of a set $X$ is free on $X$.
I am trying to show that the set of reduced words on a set $X$ is exactly the free group of $X$, i.e., it satisfies the universal property:

Universal property for free groups. There exists a map $\iota: X \to F(X)$ such that for any group $G$ and any set function $\phi: X \to G$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\Phi: F(X) \to G$ such that $\Phi \circ \iota = \phi$.

Below is where I'm at so far. Basically, I am not convinced about my proof that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism (or at least I think that this part seems incomplete or worse, incorrect.)
Proof.
Consider the inclusion map $\iota: X \to F(X)$ that sends each element of $X$ to the corresponding letter in $F(X)$. Let $G$ be a group and let $\phi: X \to G$ be a set function; we want to construct a group homomorphism $\Phi: F(X) \to G$ such that $\Phi \circ \iota = \phi$. Now since $F(X)$ is the set of reduced words in $X$, each $w \in F(X)$ is of the form
$$
    w = x_1^{\epsilon_1} x_2^{\epsilon_2} \cdots x_n^{\epsilon_n}
$$
where each $x_i \in X$ and each $\epsilon_i = \pm 1$. We define $\Phi(w)$ to be the product
$$
    \Phi(w) = \phi(x_1)^{\epsilon_1} \phi(x_2)^{\epsilon_2} \cdots \phi(x_n)^{\epsilon_n}.
$$
The expression $\phi(x)^{-1}$ is defined because $\phi(x) \in G$ and inverses exist in $G$.
Now this is the part that I would like to hear some feedback.
We claim that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism. First observe that $\Phi$ preserves the juxtaposition operation, i.e., for any two words $w_1 = x_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots x_m^{\epsilon_m}$ and $w_2 = y_1^{\delta_1} \cdots y_n^{\delta_n}$ ($\epsilon_i, \delta_i = \pm 1$, $x_i, y_i \in X$) in $F(X)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \Phi(w_1 w_2) &= \Phi(x_1^{\epsilon_1} \cdots x_m^{\epsilon_m} y_1^{\delta_1} \cdots y_n^{\delta_n})\\
    &=  \phi(x_1)^{\epsilon_1} \cdots \phi(x_m)^{\epsilon_m} \phi(y_1)^{\delta_1} \cdots \phi(y_n)^{\delta_n}\\
    &= (\phi(x_1)^{\epsilon_1} \cdots \phi(x_m)^{\epsilon_m})(\phi(y_1)^{\delta_1} \cdots \phi(y_n)^{\delta_n})\\
    &= \Phi(w_1) \Phi(w_2).
\end{align*}
Now since any word $w' \in W(X)$ has a unique reduction $w \in F(X)$, it follows that $\phi(\overline{w'}) = \phi(w)$ (here $\overline{w}$ is the unique reduction of $w$) and thus $\Phi$ also preserves the reduction operation. Moreover, $\Phi$ and $\phi$ must then agree on all reduced words and therefore for all words $u, v \in F(X)$, we have
$$
    \Phi(u \cdot v) = \Phi(\overline{uv}) = \phi(\overline{uv}) = \phi(u) \phi(v) = \Phi(u) \Phi(v).
$$
(Here the notation $u \cdot v$ is multiplication in $F(X)$, i.e., $\overline{uv}$.)
Thus $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism and the diagram commutes. Since $\Phi$ is determined by $\phi$, it is unique.

You should really specify that you are trying to show that the set of reduced words on $X$, with operation juxtaposition-and-reduction, is the free group. Though I guess that is often communicated by context, if you are checking the basic properties of the object, you should really specify the object explicitly.

Thanks! This is a useful reminder. The text I'm using earlier established that $F(X)$ is a group with the juxtaposition (followed by reduction if needed) as the group operation so left that out here but I understand it would be helpful to mention that too.

You write:

Now since any word $w' \in W(X)$ has a unique reduction $w \in F(X)$, it follows that $\phi(\overline{w'}) = \phi(w)$ (here $\overline{w}$ is the unique reduction of $w$) and thus $\Phi$ also preserves the reduction operation.

This does not actually make sense as written. $\phi$ is a function from $X$ to $G$, so it is only defined on elements of $X$. You cannot talk about $\phi(\overline{w'})$ or $\phi(w)$ unless $w$ and $\overline{w'}$ are in $X$... in which case they are reduced "words" anyway and there is nothing to prove. So the premise to your conclusion does not make sense as written, and the assertion that $\Phi$ "preserves reduction" is thus unjustified.
(I will identify $X$ with its image under $\iota$, thus taking $X$ to be a subset of the underlying set of $F$).
To prove that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism, first we prove that if $w$ is a reduced word and $x\in X$, then $\Phi(xw) = \Phi(x)\Phi(w)$, and $\Phi(x^{-1}w) = \Phi(x^{-1})\Phi(w)$. Indeed, if we can prove this, then using the fact that the group operation of "juxtaposition and reduction" on $F$ is associative, and induction on the length of the reduction of $w$, it follows that $\Phi(ww') = \Phi(w)\Phi(w')$.
Write the reduced word $w$ as $w=x_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots x_{r}^{\epsilon_r}$. If $x\neq x_1$, or if $x_1=x$ and $\epsilon_1=1$, then $xw$ is reduced, so
$$\Phi(x)\Phi(w) = \phi(x)(\phi(x_1)^{\epsilon_1}\cdots\phi(x_r)^{\epsilon_r}) = \phi(x)\phi(x_1)^{\epsilon_1}\cdots\phi(x_r)^{\epsilon_r} = \Phi(xw).$$
If $x=x_1$ and $\epsilon_1=-1$, then the reduced word corresponding to $xw$ is $x_2^{\epsilon_2}\cdots x_r^{\epsilon_r}$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\Phi(xw) &= \Phi(x_2^{\epsilon_2}\cdots x_r^{\epsilon_r})\\
 &= \phi(x_2)^{\epsilon_2}\cdots \phi(x_r)^{\epsilon_r}\\
&= \phi(x_1)\phi(x_1)^{-1}\phi(x_2)^{\epsilon_2}\cdots\phi(x_r)^{\epsilon_r}\\
&= \phi(x)\bigl( \phi(x_1)^{-1}\phi(x_2)^{\epsilon_2}\cdots\phi(x_r)^{\epsilon_r}\bigr)\\
&= \Phi(x)\Phi(w),
\end{align*}$$
as desired. A similar argument establishes $\Phi(x^{-1}w) = \Phi(x^{-1})\Phi(w)$.
Now let $w_1$ and $w_2$ be reduced words, and let $n$ be the length of $w_1$. We do induction on $n$. The result is the computation above if $n=1$. Assuming the result holds for $w_1$ of length $k$, assume
$$w_1 = x_0^{\epsilon_0}x_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots x_k^{\epsilon_k}$$
is a reduced word in $X$. Then $w_1w_2 = x_0^{\epsilon_0}(w_1'w_2)$, where
$$w_1'  = x_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots x_k^{\epsilon_k}.$$
Let $w_3$ be the reduced word corresponding to $w_1'w_2$, so that $w_1w_2 = x_0^{\epsilon_0}w_3$, though this expression need not be reduced. Note that by induction, $\Phi(w_3) = \Phi(w_1'w_2) = \Phi(w_1')\Phi(w_2)$. So we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\Phi(w_1w_2) &= \Phi(x_0^{\epsilon_0}(w_1'w_2))\\
&= \Phi(x_0^{\epsilon_0}w_3)\\
&= \Phi(x_0^{\epsilon_0})\Phi(w_3) &\text{(by the }n=1\text{ case)}\\
&= \Phi(x_0^{\epsilon_0})\Bigl(\Phi(w_1')\Phi(w_2)\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(\Phi(x_0^{\epsilon_0})\Phi(w_1')\Bigr)\Phi(w_2)\\
&= \Phi(x_0^{\epsilon_0}w_1')\Phi(w_2) &\text{(by the }n=1\text{ case)}\\
&= \Phi(w_1)\Phi(w_2).
\end{align*}$$
This shows that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism. By construction, $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)$ for each $x\in X$, and uniqueness follows because $X$ generates $F$

Thank you for the detailed response! This cleared things up a lot. I feel silly about the part where I write $\phi(w)$. I never thought about proving $\Phi(x)\Phi(w)$ first and proceeding by induction and associativity but this is really neat. Thanks again!

@RoelChristian: If you have ever seen van der Waerden's trick for proving that juxtaposition-and-reduction is associative, doing it for a single letter and then doing induction suggests itself here (at least to me).

I saw that mentioned in Hungerford but I can't bring myself to read his discussion on free groups because the typography is just awful and it's a pain to read with all the subscripts and superscripts (sorry for the petty reason). I am taking my queue in the original proof from Aluffi although he proceeds a bit differently. Now that you mentioned it though I should probably try reading Hungerford's discussion.

@RoelChristian May I suggest George Bergman's exposition in his An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions (link to the revised PDF)? Starting at the bottom of page 44 (which is labeled as page 37)

Thanks a lot! I will give this a read — the contents seem fun!

. n i c e . . .
